# Caching sql queries output on application server

Tags: php, mysql

Is there a way to save a specific mysql query output in a file on my application server (not the DB server) and update this data every n seconds so that the users do not send queries to my db but just load the cached output?

I thought about using a crontab which opens a specific .php that executes the queries and saves the data to a file which is loaded when the users demand the data. If this is a good idea, is it possible to make this .php file not accessible from public http requests?

Comment: a wild goose chase. Why do you even want to do this??

Comment: To reduce IOPS on my db.

Comment: There should be no need to do this. MySql already has a [query cache](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html), so you will not gain much, if anything.

Comment: Have you considered application caching. It will cache data in your application in a data store, you can check before loading data from db if the cache exists then use that. However it becomes complex if you need to keep track of when your cache has become dirty and needs to be reloaded.  Here is a tutorial that goes over some of it, http://blog.digitalstruct.com/2008/02/27/php-performance-series-caching-techniques/. I think this can add a lot of complexity to your code.

Comment: Actually the main "problem" or better: opportunity is that all users send the same query to the db. But considering the answer of @Gorfdon Linoff I will avoid this method and maybe use application caching as a compromise to prevent multiple queries of a single user in a defined time period. Thanks for this idea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, this is probably not a good idea.  If your goal is to reduce I/O, you may be actually increasing it when the user load is low.

Second, if you do this, you will probably need to write custom code to maintain the local cache.  You then have issues of cache contention -- particularly when writes and reads are happening at the same time.

Third, if the problem is that queries are taking too long (which is not clear because you are focused on I/O bandwidth), then optimizing the database and queries would be a first step.

Fourth, lots of data being returned from the database to the application often suggests a poor design of the data interface.  Thinking through what is needed can be really helpful.  For instance, perhaps sorting on the server and returning the first 10 rows is the best solution.  Or, perhaps, counting on the database side is the right solution.

Finally, any solution of this sort necessarily means that the local cache can be out-of-sync with the database.  This is usually the killer problem with this type of approach.

All of these can be solved, but they generally go in the direction of making the code more complex.  If you don't have a real performance problem now, then remember what Knuth advised:  "Premature optimization is the root of all evil."  (I agree with the sentiment but there is definitely other evil out there in the world ;)

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer. I am developing a browser extension and just don't want that my servers break down if it goes viral. The query I want to cache is exactly the same one for every user and it does not matter if it is not 100% synchronous with the db but I will first try and see if it works without my "complex" method. Thank you

Comment: @JuliusS. if it goes viral, and you have a workable revenue model, that is a sweet issue. I would put "premature caching" as en even `eviler` evil category, because in many cases it is just an illusion, from a performance standpoint.

Comment: @YvesLeBorg Ok well, then I think I can start working on the rest of my code and forget about this "problem" :D

Comment: @JuliusS. . . . The one thing I would say is to structure your code so the accesses to the database defined through an API.  That way, you can implement a cache if you want, without significant modifications to your code.

Comment: I'm not that deep into developing that I can understand how I can use an API to request data from my db. I'm into using APIs like the one of fb but never created one myself.